# response.sendRedirect() from Servlet to JSP does not seem to work

Tags: redirect, servlets

I am writing a client server program. I am sending an arraylist from an android phone and I am able to receive the list also. After that I want the servlet to redirect to `demo.jsp` using `response.sendRedirect()`, but it just won't redirect. Tried with `requestDispatcher.forward()` too.

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream((InputStream) request.getInputStream());
List<Double> al=(List<Double>)in.readObject();
in.close();
for(int x=0;x<al.size();x++)
{
    System.out.println("List");
    System.out.println(al.get(x));
}
System.out.println("going to demo.jsp");
response.sendRedirect("demo.jsp");
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: and your client is ? is it a browser or something ?

Comment: I am sending the requests from an android phone. I have an app built and it is from that app the requests are being made.

Comment: Reminder to self: delete this totally misleading question once it's finally closed.

Answer (score 46):

I'm posting this answer because the one with the most votes led me astray.  To redirect from a servlet, you simply do this:

```
response.sendRedirect("simpleList.do")
```

In this particular question, I think @M-D is correctly explaining why the asker is having his problem, but since this is the first result on google when you search for "Redirect from Servlet" I think it's important to have an answer that helps most people, not just the original asker.

Comment: The OP is doing a `response.sendRedirect` already in his code. How does it actually solve the OP's problem?

Comment: This doesn't work. simpleList.do isn't anywhere in the OPs post or my project.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of using

```
response.sendRedirect("/demo.jsp");
```

Which does a permanent redirect to an absolute URL path,

Rather use `RequestDispatcher`. Example:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("demo.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried that too but no use. I doesnt work !!

Comment: @zoozo, are you receiving requests from the Android app? If so, can you do a dispatch to `"/demo.jsp"` instead?

Comment: I am sending an arraylist from the android app. I can get the list in my servlet and can also fetch the values from the list but only this redirection part isn't working. I will try dispatching to `"/demo.jsp"` and will let you know.

Comment: where is demo.jsp placed in your web application?

Comment: @Buhake : You seem to be a good professional(looking at your score), so I assume you didn't read his question clearly. In his case, he has already sent some responses (response "body" too), and hence it wont be possible to have a permanent redirect with **sendRedirect**.

Comment: @M-D, if you see clearly, the OP has not posted anything substantial for us to tell exactly why the issue persists. We don't have any stacktrace or HTTP response code whatsoever. The only way is to ask "redundant" questions to see **how** the OP is doing Servlet redirection.

Answer (score -3):

Since you already have sent some data,

```
System.out.println("going to demo.jsp");
```

you won't be able to send a redirect.

Comment: the data was sent to System.out, so it doesn't affect the servlet response

Answer (score -3):

You can use this:

```
response.sendRedirect(String.format("%s%s", request.getContextPath(), "/views/equipment/createEquipment.jsp"));
```

The last part is your path in your web-app

Comment: Please elaborate further on your answer.